# Help identifying connector - Hyundai USB outlet

Tags: identification, connector, automotive, crimp

I want to find this connector... (found in my 2022 Hyundai Ioniq 5 - for connecting to the OEM USB outlets in the centre console)
[image: USB Connector]

The car has this 4-pin female end, which I would like to use without tampering or splicing... so I need to find the end (above) that is used on the (now removed) 12V USB socket, so I can upgrade to after-market sockets that use the standard 2 blade connectors.

This image below is captured from this installation YouTube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-7DyulibPg).
[image: Car Connector]

I need 2 of the "Male" connectors - preferably with pigtail leads (same as in the OEM USB socket) and then crimp on spade connectors to the after-market USB-C outlets... that way, the modification is 100% reversible, but still safe & secure.

Measuring the pins, they seem to be 2.5 (or possibly 2.54mm) pitch.  But I can't seem to find a connector with the same locking mechanism. JST-XH style connectors do fit in the pin holes just fine... but that solution is lacking the locking mechanism (so I hot glued it in place as a temporary solution... not ideal long-term)

Measurements:

- overall width of the opening: 11.25mm
- height: 5.85mm
- depth: 12.55mm
- pitch appears to be about 2.5mm (or maybe 2.54mm)

Comment: Can you have some measurements (width, height, pitch)?

Comment: overall width of the opening:  11.25mm

height: 5.85mm

depth: 12.55mm

pitch appears to be about 2.5mm (or maybe 2.54mm)

Comment: tbh, now that I've dis-assembled the connector, I think I might just whip up a design in CAD and 3D print a connector/adapter.  :P

Comment: did you end up finding a matching connector or did you 3d print one? I'm in the same boat with my ioniq 5

Comment: Is that solid core wire? In an automotive application?